# How to condition file name shorter?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I have some images named: e14_A_0002, e14_B_0002, e14_8_0001, e14_9_0001 ...
I used to set condition for the file name like below and it works good:

```
var fileName1 = doc.name.indexOf ("_A_") != -1 || doc.name.indexOf ("_B_") != -1;
var fileName2 = doc.name.indexOf ("_8_") != -1 || doc.name.indexOf ("_9_") != -1;

if ( fileName1 == true ) 
{
    doAction (1)
}

else if ( fileName2 == true )
{
    doAction (2)
}

else 
{
    doAction (3)
}
```

But the variable will be too long if I list all of them.
I've tried // var fileName = doc.name.indexOf ("*7*") , ("*8*") != -1 // but it doesn't work. Please help me if there is a shorter way for that!!!

Comment: Are you always going to be looking at characters 4-6 ("_A_") in the filename? ie are all the files going to start with "e14"? Regular Expressions may help you out here.

Comment: The characters before and after "_A_" are different, maybe less or more.
Just the "_A"_ or "_8_" will always there.

Comment: *"the variable will be too long"* You mean the expressions would be too long? If the underscores are always like that you could [split the string](https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/Core/String/split.html#string-split) at `_` and then switch/case for the array's `[1]` value

Comment: @PeterKrebs but the letters from A to Z, I mean 
// doc.name.indexOf ("_A_") != -1 || .... || doc.name.indexOf ("_Z_") != -1 //
I would like the code like that // doc.name.indexOf ("A"), ("B"), ..., ("Z")  != -1 //

Comment: If you split at `_` the letter will be at `[1]` in the array. And then you write a switch/case statement for all the letters. You can't change the syntax of indexOf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a way to to peform an action based on the filename. But using if else gets a bit clunky. This should springboard you to where you want to go.

```
var fileName = "e14_A_0002"; // doc.name
var letter = fileName[4]; //  "A" in this example


switch (letter)
{
  case "A": action = 1;
            break;
  case "B": action = 2;
            break;
  default:  action = 3;
}

alert(letter + ": doAction(" + action + ")");
```